# Trouble with loading jquery onload

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-tabs, document-ready

I'm trying to build some jquery tabs based on the request (which is stored in a table).

I have two pages sharing one .js file. One page is for the user to create the request, and the other is for the administrator to approve/deny the request.

On the admin page, here is my javascript code:

```
    $(function() {
        GetRequest();
    });
```

Which is just calling a function I have inside my .js file.

All the code in the .js file is also wrapped in a '$(function(){ //...code here })'.

The problem is the function isn't built yet when calling it from the page. Is there a way I can tell the page to wait until the script is complete?

Comment: I think we're going to need to see a little more of your code to figure out what your doing and what's going wrong :)  

also: functions don't need to go inside the $(function(){})  that's where you put any jquery or other javascript that you want to have called when the document loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't wrap the code inside the `.js` file in the `$(function(){ ... })` code. It puts the function inside of an instance that you can't access outside of that ready function. Then on both the admin and user page, call the appropriate functions inside the `.js` file